# Customizing template in magento2

Tags: magento2, template, customize

I need help in 2 questions:

> 1 - Put a delay for the newsletter popup to open after the uploaded
>   website + 10s
>
> 2 - I have 2 javascript (tidio and whatshelp.io) in
>   the footer, the problem occurs when I insert an item in the cart, my
>   template goes up a bar with the item and the chat icon is on top, I
>   wanted to reposition it

1- The newsletter block has the content
[image]
And here the content of the popup_subscribe.phtml

```
// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile
?>
<div class="block newsletter">
    <div class="title"><strong><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Newsletter') ?></strong></div>
    <div class="content">
        <form class="form subscribe"
            novalidate
            action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getFormActionUrl() ?>"
            method="post"
            data-mage-init='{"validation": {"errorClass": "mage-error"}}'
            id="popup-newsletter-validate-detail">
            <div class="field newsletter">
                <label class="label" for="newsletter"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Sign Up for Our Newsletter:') ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input name="email" type="email" id="popup-newsletter"
                                placeholder="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Enter your email address') ?>"
                                data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="actions">
                <button class="action subscribe primary" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Subscribe') ?>" type="submit">
                    <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Subscribe') ?></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

2- Example of code inserted in the footer

```
<script src="//code.tidio.co/......js"></script>
<!-- WhatsHelp.io widget -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        var options = {
...
...
</script>
<!-- /WhatsHelp.io widget -->
```

Whatshelp icon overlay image over bar checkout button.
[image]